# How can I turn off the majority of hbm2ddl's output in the console in Ant?

Tags: java, hibernate, ant, build-process, hbm2ddl

By default, hbm2ddl spits a ton of output to the console when executing the ant task.  I'd like to turn this completely off and simply look at the schema file if something has gone wrong.  Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: I'm interested in an answer for this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate (at least the current version) uses [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) for logging. Use the SLF4J NOP to silently discarding all logging. Alternatively you could configure a low level verbosity for your logging framework (e.g. [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/)).

A sample log4j.properties:

```
### direct log messages to stdout ###
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug
```

Comment: Could you update this with a snippet example?  Other than that, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is undocumented property which should be defined in  task:

```
<hibernatetool ....>

   <property key="scriptToConsole" value="false"/>

...

   <hbm2ddl ....../>

</hibernatetool>
```

For me it works!